# Making a JavaScript button selector

Tags: javascript, button, selection

I'm somewhat new to JavaScript and web-based programming, and a pet project I'm working on would really benefit from replacing terrible-looking radio buttons with actual button selectors that worked the same way as radio buttons.

A picture is worth a thousand words, but apparently I cannot post an image until my reputation increases, so let me try to describe this to you.

> A **horiozontal radio button list** is a list of text items, enumerated in
>   a horizontal row, with a selectable "circle" preceeding it.  If one
>   item is selected, the little "circle" preceeding it is filled in. 
>   Only one item in the list can be selected at once.
>
> A **horizontal button selector list** is a horizontal grouping of buttons,
>   with text in the center of each button representing the item to be
>   selected.  When you select the button with the item in the center, the
>   button color changes somehow to show that it is the selected item. 
>   Only one button in the group can be selected at once.

The benefit of the button selection versus radio button selection is that it is easier for tablet and touch-screen users to select the items in a horizontal button selector list instead of a horizontal radio button list, and it is more visually appealing.

I have been able to figure out how to do vertical radio buttons, and horizontal radio buttons, but I want to extend the selector button idea and turn it into actual buttons.  Can anyone provide a starting point for this?  I have over 30 "topics" needing selection, and I can have up to 20 items to select from for a single "topic", so I want this to involve the least amount of coding as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out Twitter Bootstrap? This may be what you're looking for:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

There's also a newer version optimized for touch devices:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can look into jQuery UI, there are the horizontal radio button selector list you mentioned above work this way:

http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio